# Have/had crisis deepen

Tags: grammaticality, interpretation

> - This year we have economic crisis deepen in our country.
> - This year we had economic crisis deepen in our country.

Are they both grammatical and sensical? If yes, then how do you read both examples? I am interested in your interpretation.

Comment: Where from did you get these sentences? Did you made them up yourself? In that case please tell what you want to mean.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the helper verb (to have) with the verb:

> This year *an/the* economic crisis **has deepened** in our country.

or

> This year *an/the* economic crisis **had deepened** in our country, but the government took several actions to improve the situation.

Comment: Thanks. I have some questions: 1) can't we use _crisis_ as an uncountable noun here (why?)  2) what's the reason for using the structure _have smth do_ as compared to your examples (perhaps that makes a difference?) 3) do you have any links to rules (I can't find info on Internet).

Comment: I think a "crisis" cannot be uncountable, since it refers to a specific event/situation. It would have to be "crisis" or "crises" (plural). You could say "This year economic *crises* have deepened in our country..."

Answer (score 0):

Both are more or less correct. Just add an article. Like so:

> This year we *have* **an** economic crisis deepen in our country.
>
> This year we *had* **an** economic crisis deepen in our country.

The one with have is that they still have a crisis. The one with had is that someone had a crisis this year, but they no longer have it.

Comment: I read the the tense different than you an expected: This year we have had an eco...   All for lack of an article and/or helper verb.